# Mobile view layout ordering

Tags: human-interface-guideline, alignment, page-layout, ux-integration

I'm confused about one of my eCommerce project product details page ! I couldn't understand am I keep right sidebar on top in mobile ? Now its after logo.[image: eCommerce-product]

Moreover I want to keep social media and newsletter form design based on this screen.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

No you don't keep the sidebar on mobile, since your horizontal space is more limited then your vertical space.

Here is an example of a product-detail page on mobile.3

[image]

Comment: In mobile my sidebar automatically goes down! So I have a concern about whether its comes first or not, but the screenshot you give it clear to me.
-Thank You